# Does gradle continuous build support SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

When I try to run `build` with gradle with the `-t` flag:

```
./gradlew clean build -x test -t
```

I get prompt line:

> Waiting for changes to input files of tasks... (ctrl-d to exit)

but when I try it with `bootRun` command it doesn't work/appear:

```
./gradlew clean bootRun -t
```

Does it work with Spring Boot? (I know about Spring [dev tools plugin](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3) - 1.3 is not released yet)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your Spring Boot application. If you app typically runs and then exits then continuous build will work. However if your app typically stays alive indefinitely, for example because it's a web app that handles HTTP requests, then it won't work. In the latter case the `bootRun` task never completes so Gradle doesn't know that it's time to start watching for changes.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In that case, do you know any workarounds for that kind of indefinitely tasks (ex. bootRun)?

Answer (score 23):

[andy-wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) is correct in his answer : `gradle bootRun` never completes because some applications run indefinitely. Its well documented in this [issue in the grails project](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641).

I've found a way to force bootRun to live reload the application from the command line. The key items here are the [gradle daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) and the [spring-boot-devtools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3) package.

To get it to live reload you need to have 2 terminals open.

1. `gradle build --continuous`

   - [build --continuous](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/continuous_build.html)  will keep satisfying the initial build request until stopped
   - `gradle build --continuous --quiet & 2>1 >/dev/null` runs in the background, but you would miss the important build warnings/errors. `gradle --stop` to stop watching.
2. `gradle bootRun`

   - [Bootrun](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications) starts with spring-boot-devtools on classpath, which will detect changes and restart application.