# Automatically reload static content with Jetty and Gradle

Tags: java, web, gradle, jetty, static-content

I would like static content updates to be reflected in my web app without restarting web server. I am using gradle with jetty plugin.

How can I do that?

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
...
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:5.14.2'
}
```

Here is part of my `web.xml` for static content:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this feature is not enabled with `jetty` plugin. Gradle from (AFAIR) version 2.6 supports [continuous build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/continuous_build.html) but I've tried it with jetty and spring-boot and it [wasn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512195/does-gradle-continuous-build-support-springboot). You may try of course and please let me know if you've succeeded.

What you may also try is [gretty](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Feature-overview.html).

P.S. I'm also not sure if static content must/should be mapped via `web.xml` - it may be put directly under `WEB-INF` - but I may be wrong.