# Spring Boot bootRun with continuous build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

It should be possible to have a Spring Boot app continuously build (i.e. hot reload) by running `gradle build --continuous` and `gradle bootRun` in sequence.

I'm trying to modify the bootRun task in the gradle build file so that it calls the build task in continuous mode, but I can't seem to add arguments to it.

```
bootRun.dependsOn build
```

How can I get that build to run continuously?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[This question and the corresponding answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512195/does-gradle-continuous-build-support-springboot/41878387) are pretty interesting.

[Short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513252/2003986) : you can't have the `bootRun` task running with the `continuous`  option (if your app stays alive indefinitely)

But there is [a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41878387/2003986) by Stefan Crain :

> To get it to live reload you need to have 2 terminals open.
>
> 1. `gradle build --continuous`
>
>    - build --continuous  will keep satisfying the initial build request until stopped
>    - `gradle build --continuous --quiet & 2>1 >/dev/null` runs in the background, but you would miss the important build warnings/errors.
>        `gradle --stop` to stop watching.
> 2. `gradle bootRun`
>
>    - bootrun starts with spring-boot-devtools on classpath, which will detect changes and restart application.

I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: FYI `gradle build --continuous -xtest` skips `test` task which I think would be the expectation in this answer.

Comment: For me using the `build` task as a "sentinel" didn't work, as during the restart bootRun couldn't find the main class name anymore. I've replaced it with the `bootRunMainClassName` task, which is the task `bootRun` directly depends upon and that also exits upon completion. This also makes sure that upon changes all the tasks `bootRun` depends have a chance to run and update.

Comment: As 2022 you can just do `gradle bootRun --continuous`

Comment: neither solution works. I just update a simple Controller to return something different but curl gives the same output as before

Answer (score 9):

To get hot reload using Gradle in Spring boot first you need dependency(if you are using Gradle Kotlin)
Put this into build.gradle

```
developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

Then you have to open terminal and run command

```
gradle -t :bootJar
```

and then open a new terminal and run command

```
gradle bootRun
```

This will solve the problem for hot reload.

Comment: this works! Also for Java

Answer (score -1):

Another option to Toyonos solution seems to work for me, run the commands in two separate terminals to maintain the build warning messages:

- gradle bootRun
- gradle build --continuous

Comment: good question... maybe his answer was changed, or I put this on the wrong question, don't remember.

Comment: I see no edits on the accepted answer. Probably the other option