# spring boot dockerRun with auto restart with remote debug never turning on

Tags: gradle, remote-debugging, spring-boot-devtools, bootrun

I'm making application spring boot project.
I'm trying to make developing environment using bootRun with auto restart in `spring-boot-devtools`.

I saw the how to do that via this question.
[Spring Boot bootRun with continuous build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092504/spring-boot-bootrun-with-continuous-build)

The difference between me is I am running `build --continuous` at background.
because, I have to run this application on docker container.

But, with remote debug it never tunrs on.
without remote debug option, it turns on quickly.

I saw log like this 'lock something...'.
I think it may be problem.

Here's part of log.

```
...

2023-03-27T04:36:03.683+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
2023-03-27T04:36:03.691+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-19.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'.
2023-03-27T04:36:03.710+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
2023-03-27T04:36:03.710+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
2023-03-27T04:36:03.714+0900 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-19.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
2023-03-27T04:36:03.757+0900 [QUIET] [system.out] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
2023-03-27T04:36:08.682+0900 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] 
2023-03-27T04:36:08.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:08.683+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:08.683+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:08.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:08.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:08.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:18.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:18.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:18.683+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:18.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:18.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:18.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:28.680+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:28.680+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:28.681+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:28.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:28.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:28.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:32.825+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.828+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.828+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 9: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.829+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 9: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.829+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 2: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.829+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 2: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.829+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] included builds: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.829+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] included builds: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.829+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 8: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 8: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 7: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 7: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 6: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 6: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 5: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 5: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.830+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 3: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.831+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 3: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.831+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 4: acquired lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:32.831+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 4: released lock on worker lease
2023-03-27T04:36:38.682+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:38.683+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:38.683+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:38.684+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:38.685+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-03-27T04:36:38.688+0900 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [45s]
> :bootRun
```

Is it impossible to run two gradle task in one terminal?

```
FROM gradle:latest

WORKDIR /was

ENTRYPOINT gradle build --continuous & gradle bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev' -PjvmArgs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=${DEBUG_PORT}"
```

in code, `-PjvmArgs` process with this `build.gralde.kts` file.

```kotlin
...

configurations {
  create("dev")
}

tasks.bootRun {
  classpath += sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath + configurations.getByName("dev")

  if (project.hasProperty("jvmArgs")) {
        jvmArgs = (project.property("jvmArgs") as String).split("\\s+")
    }
}
```

I expected that two gradle task works normally in one terminal.

I tried gradle options like this.
`--parallel`, `--daemon`.

But, nothing's changed.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

the stuck is 'normal' state.

I have to attach debugger. and, it processes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).